# What is the fundamental group of 4 lines with endpoints identified?

Tags: algebraic-topology

Given $4$ $1-$simplex, put an orientation on each of them, identified all of their starting and end points together. How to calculate the fundamental group of this space?

I tried Van-kampen by taking an open set around the starting point but the intersection will not be path connected.

Answer (score 2):

collapse one of the lines -> get a bouquet of three circles.